# Easiest method to implement fancy CSS/Javascript navigation menu in Drupal 6?

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, content-management-system, drupal-theming

I've implemented the required functionality for my Drupal (6.19) web site, and I'm now in a position where I'd like to enhance the look and feel of the site. The current theme is a Zen sub-theme, with minimal modifications.

Can anyone explain what the simplest approach to implement a fancy CSS/Javascript menu, like this?: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/drop-down-menu/. I understand HTML and I have a passive understanding of PHP, SQL and CSS.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for: [Nice Menus module](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) and it's [documentation](http://drupal.org/node/185543).

The configuration is easy as you can see on the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I have 'nice menus' and 'superfish' modules installed, and I've assigned 'Superfish 1' block to the 'Navigation bar' region. The result isn't pretty: http://img84.imageshack.us/i/screenshotfb.png/. As you can see, the menu text is obscured by the content title. To resolve this issue, is it best to edit 'sites/all/modules/superfish/css/superfish-navbar.css' or the CSS files in 'sites/all/themes/mytheme/css'?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useful link on the subject without using a module like Nice menus or superfish: http://drupal.org/node/190263

If you use this approach be sure under site building > menus > primary links (or whatever menu you're using) you have the "expanded" option checked under the items you want to drop down.